# Spark SQL correlated subquery not identifying parent columns

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I am trying to migrate a query from SQL Server to Spark SQL. It is running fine on SQL Server but having issues in Spark SQL. I found that spark SQL does not support sub queries But I am avoiding to make lot of changes to this query as it was provided by DBA.

```
SELECT g.HTRAN
FROM property pr
inner join gldetail g on g.hprop = pr.hmy
INNER JOIN acct ac on g.hacct = ac.hmy
INNER JOIN trans tr on tr.hmy = g.htran
INNER JOIN accttreexref x on ac.hmy = x.hacct
INNER JOIN accttreedetail a on a.hmy = x.hdetail
LEFT OUTER JOIN person r ON (g.hperson = r.hmy)
WHERE a.htree = 4
AND x.hdetail IN (SELECT hDetail
                        FROM accttreexref actx
                        WHERE hAcct IN (
                                SELECT hmy
                                FROM acct
                                WHERE SCODE IN (
                                        SELECT ownremitac1
                                        FROM PROPBUT_OCASH po
                                        WHERE po.HCODE = pr.hmy
                                        )
                                )
                            AND Htree IN (
                                SELECT a.hmy
                                FROM AcctTree a
                                WHERE scode = tr.hmy
                                )
                        )
```

So when I am running it PO.HCODE = pr.hmy condition is unable to find pr.hmy which is the parent column and similar is the case with tr.hmy.

Comment: Your DBA is supplying you with scripts that still use comma joins? They kind of went out of vogue with SQL92 and Spark SQL makes no mention of supporting them.

Comment: Actually its just for replicating a legacy report you can consider them as join i can make that change.